# Can't make POST request via fetch javascript to django rest api

Tags: javascript, django-rest-framework, fetch-api

i just started to learn front-end and javascript.
So, previously i made simple api via django rest framework.
And now - start to test it via fetch-api of javascript.
GET - no problem - it works well.
POST - i got a message like:
"415 Unsupported media type".

Here my simplified html-file (tryjs.html) with included fetch POST request:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
</head>

<body>
     <script>
        let myurl2 = "http://127.0.0.1:8000/myfamily/";
        async function myfu() {
            let response = await fetch(myurl2, {
                mode: "no-cors",
                method: 'POST',
                headers: {
                    'Accept': 'application/json',
                    'Content-Type': 'application/json'
                },
                body: JSON.stringify({firstname: "first", secondname: "second"})
            })
        };
        myfu();
    </script>
</body>

</html>
```

Looks like pretty simple and nothing special.

Here - the model.py from drf:

```
from django.db import models


class Family(models.Model):
    firstname = models.CharField(max_length=20)
    secondname = models.CharField(max_length=20)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.firstname
```

And serializers.py:

```
from rest_framework import serializers
from .models import Family


class FamilySerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    class Meta:
        model = Family
        fields = ('firstname', 'secondname')
```

And view:

```
from rest_framework import viewsets
from .models import Family
from .serializers import FamilySerializer


class FamilyViewSet(viewsets.ModelViewSet):
    queryset = Family.objects.all()
    serializer_class = FamilySerializer
```

And urls.py of applications (added to urls.py of project):

```
from django.urls import path
from rest_framework.routers import SimpleRouter
from .views import FamilyViewSet
from django.views.generic import TemplateView


router = SimpleRouter()
router.register('', FamilyViewSet, basename="family")

urlpatterns = [
    path('tryjs/', TemplateView.as_view(template_name="tryjs.html")),
]

urlpatterns += router.urls
```

I do GET and POST request via postman - everything works fine.
I do GET request via javascript script (i've delited this part from code above) - it works fine either.
As soon, as i try to make POST request via js script above - i get a failure about wrong media type.
Please, help. I tried a lot. And it's so simple case. However...it doesn't work(

Comment: I don't know about python, but it seems you are trying to accept json response, but the response is html which it's generated by view engine.

Answer (score 0):

you are getting  wrong media type because you have set `mode: "no-cors"`, which makes
`Content-Type` header to be immutable. so setting it to `"application/json"` will automatically transformed to `"text/plain"`. keep `mode :"cors"` and it will work.

No need to write the js code yourself, you will get the code from postman itself. try using that

Comment: Yes, you are right about "no-cors". I've changed it and...started to get another problem, caused by "wrong csrf token". Seems like i don't have any authorization included (no login in view, etc.), but...
Tried to switch off csrf for all views, for each view, based on recommendations of drf - doesn't work(